# Stop Specific CoreData Record Being Deleted?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, core-data

I have CoreData setup in my app and I have an entity with an attribute 'isSpecial' boolean. For the records where 'isSpecial' is true, I want those records to not be deletable by the user from the UITableView it is displayed within.

So how can I do this? How do I directly see that the cell selected by the user 'isSpecial'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `NSManagedObject` for your entity (if you haven't already), and override `validateForDelete:` to check the `isSpecial` property of the object.

You should also call super's implementation, [as detailed here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/validateForDelete%3a).

If and when you want to delete it programmatically, you'll just need to set `isSpecial` to `NO` before you attempt the delete.

Comment: This may stop the actual data being deleted but the cell is still deletable from the tableview.

Comment: That hadn't occurred to me! @wattson12's answer is the way to go then.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using swipe to delete on the table view it may be better to is use `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` and only allow editing if `isSpecial` is false. This would stop the user hitting the delete button and nothing happening

Comment: I have tried this but how I do I access the isSpecial attribute of the object attached to that cell?

Comment: the same way you access it when you set up the cell data in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. Assuming you have an NSFetchedResultsController it would be something like MyEntity *cellEntity = [self.fetchedResultsController objectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; return ![cellEntity.isSpecial boolValue];

Comment: Oh, of course, silly me. I can do `[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]` but not `objectForRowAtIndexPath`. Should this make a difference? However Im not having any luck with this. I have a clue as to what it might be, but before I say anything which might sway your thoughts, any ideas?

Comment: sorry, i just typed that from memory, you should use `objectAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Ahh ok. I was thinking, I have a custom cell at index 0, which means I have to adjust the index path whenever accessing core data objects in the table but using this: `NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(indexPath.row - 1) inSection:indexPath.section];`. This deducts the index by one which is working for me really well in all my other tableview delegate methods, however this time it doesn't stop me from getting an index beyond bounds error and crashing the app.

Comment: the difference might be that you only get the cell object in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when you are in rows other than 0. `canEditRowAtIndexPath:` will get called for row 0, which means that you should return YES or NO for that row, and then check the value of `isSpecial` for all the other rows

Comment: I have tried if indexPath == 0 return YES, else... Then deal with isSpecial objects, but no luck, same beyond bounds error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6860/discussion-between-wattson12-and-josh-kahane)